# Html Tables aren't working right

Tags: html

My tables seem to be working differently than I would like, but as I try to reorganize it, it become worse. I'm not sure if I using TD or TR wrong or what is happening. With the code the way it is now, the horizontal navigation bar won't set a yellow border and my tables below it aren't how I want them.
It's supposed to look like this:
      Logo(top all the way across)
       Horizontal navigation bar(all the way across above vert navigation bar, history, and       gainful) 
        vert navigation bar(left to history), history,Gainful(right of history)
       about(below history in border)

```
  <body >
  <Table width=100% height=500 border=3
  bordercolor=blue>
 <TR height=20%  style="background-color:black; background-width:100%">
 <TD><img src="logo.png" alt="C"/>
 <span style="color:white; font-size:22px; float:bottom">Computer Science Department</span></TD>

 </TR>
 <TR height=10% >
 <TD style="border-color:green;border-width: 2px">
 <nav class="horizontal"style=" padding-left:0px;
 border-color:yellow;color:black; font-size:20px; width:100%; " >
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Faculty</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Programs</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Classes</a></li>
      <li><a href="ProgramList.htm">Program List</a></li>
   </ul>

 </nav>

  <nav class="vertical" style="border-color:green;text-align: center; color: black">
     <ul style="list-style-type:none">
        <li><a href="#" class="b1">Computer Programming</a></li><BR>
        <li><a href="#" class="b1">Computer Specialist</a></li><BR>
        <li><a href="#" class="b1">Information Technology Analysis</a></li><BR>
        <li><a href="#" class="b1">Information Technology Management</a></li><BR>
        <li><a href="#" class="b1">Network System Developer</a></li><BR>
        <li><a href="#" class="b1">Web Development Specialist</a></li><BR>
        </ul>
  </nav></TD>

 </TR>
 <TR height=60%>
    <TD>3 content
    <Table width=90% height=90% border=4
    bordercolor=blue>
    <TR>
   <TD >History</TD>
   <TR>
      <TD>About</TD>          
   </TR>
   <TD >Gainful</TD>






  </Table>
</TD>

 </TR>
 <TR height=10%>
<TD><footer >

 </footer></TD>

 </TR>
 </Table>

 </body>
 </html>
```

I'm not sure if that explained it well, if it didn't please let me know.

Comment: Two things: 1) run your code through an HTML validator and 2) don't use tables for layout; use tables for tabular data, use CSS for layout

Comment: @j08691 My teacher won't allow css for layout.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem was. I had some of the tables in the wrong order, which messed it up. Thank-you for the assistance.